# How do I only show products with a specific attribute based on a session var in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a zipcode/postcode based store in which you can only see products that are within a certain zipcode range. The zipcode range is an attribute of the product itself to make things easier. The costumers zipcode is stored in session (put in by a form) How would I prevent my costumers to see products that are not able to be bought in their zipcode? I'm building a child theme and would like to use code to solve this issue (no extra plugins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook into woocommerce_product_query, here is an example:

```
function so_42540393_product_query( $q ){
    if(isset($_SESSION['ZIPCODE-RANGE'])){
    $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'CUSTOM_META_KEY',
        'value' => $_SESSION['ZIPCODE-RANGE'],
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        ); 

    $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'so_42540393_product_query' );
```

This will remove them from all the stop archive pages. If they have a link for a product that is outside their range they would still be able to visit that page, but I assume that wouldn't be a problem? This is example code, so make sure you set the meta query and the session right. Does this help?