# Woocommerce meta query not works in product_query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I want to change products in woocommerce product page loop with filter

i'm try filter from url `wordpress.test/shop?filterbyAge=23` , now i added code in functions file but not working

i created felid with ACF plugin in product

```
function updateQueryByAgeFilter( $q ){ 
    if (isset($_GET['filterbyAge'])) {
    
        $q->set('meta_query', [
            [
                'key' => 'book_age_group',
                'value' => $_GET['filterbyAge'],
                'compare' => '='
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'updateQueryByAgeFilter' );
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540393/how-do-i-only-show-products-with-a-specific-attribute-based-on-a-session-var-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merging the query seems to be missing

So you get:

```php
// Change the shop query
function action_woocommerce_product_query( $q, $query ) {
    // Returns true when on the product archive page (shop) & isset
    if ( is_shop() && isset( $_GET['filterbyAge'] ) ) {        
        // Get any existing meta query
        $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
        
        // Settings
        $key = 'book_age_group';
        $value = $_GET['filterbyAge'];
        
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => $key,
            'value' => $value,
            'compare' => '='
        );

        // Set the new merged meta query
        $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'action_woocommerce_product_query', 10, 2 );
```